# aritmethic inside jquery nth-child semi colon

Tags: jquery

Can I do arithmetic inside jquery nth-child semicolon?

For example:

```
alert($('img:nth-child(2+1)'));
```

I checked many times but I still can't get the alert.

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do? You can, with `nth-child()` use (for example) `nth-child(2n+1)`, but without knowing your intent or needs, it's hard to offer any advice. (Also, you're missing a closing bracket from the `alert()`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alert($("img:nth-child("+(2+1)+")");
```